# Execute NodeJS application on SVN hook

Tags: node.js, svn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

How do I execute a [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) application on SVN [post-commit hook](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/post-commit/) at [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/)?

Can anyone provide a basic example?